# React-router-dom add loadingscreen when awaiting loader

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm developing web application and I have small problem. My goal is: Display  component until page is not ready to render. With that I mean that are any assets are still loading or if there is any loader for route until it doens't await data. My main problem is the loader blocking rendering until it's await data. There is any way to prevent from blocking and "tell"  that it should display fallback?

```
react: ^18.2.0
react-dom: ^18.2.0
react-router-dom: ^6.20.0
```

I tried with  with no effect. I can't see the fallback even for a split second

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Loader from "./Loader";

const Root: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                <Header />
                <div className="min-h-[calc(100vh-80px-154px)] lg:min-h-[calc(100vh-130px-138px)]">
                    <Outlet />
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </Suspense>
        </>
    );
};

export default Root;
```

I also check useNavigation() hook but for me state is always "idle".